# Нужно ли двоеточие и кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

А) Ее друзья сказали нет, все сказали ей нет;

Б) Нет всегда можно превратить в да;

В) Слышу крики помоги;

Г) Сначала скажи пожалуйста;

Д) Никаких потом.

Про *никаких но* говорят, что кавычки не нужны, но что, если заменить *но* на другое слово(-а)?